# Setting Variables for Rails Credentials with Production and Development Environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials

I want to introduce a production and development mode to rails credentials. If I have a base_url that is the same for both environments, can I put it outside the nest like this?

```
base_url:
   hostname: http://....

production:
   client_api_endpoint: http://...

development:
   client_api_endpoint: http://....
```

Or would base_url have to be inside production and development?

```
production:
   base_url:
     hostname: http://....
   client_api_endpoint: http://...

development:
    base_url:
       hostname: http://....
   client_api_endpoint: http://....
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, it's just how you parse the YAML, right?

Comment: Unless you have something limiting your credential scope to the environment, parsing your YAML file is just about traversing the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in `credentials.yml.enc`, all that matters is knowing how you want to access the variables.

```rb
# nested under environment 
Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :base_url, :hostname)

# outside environment 
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:base_url, :hostname)
```